Blazor 7 single sign on. Windows authentication and IIS server
I have a Blazor 7 application setup for windows authentication. I have it deployed to an IIS server. How do I implement single sign on? The site on IIS is set to windows authentication but the users still get prompted to sign in. If this was Old ASP I would set it up in the web config but I cant find anything on setting this up in Blazor 7.
Tried setting the IIS server to windows authentication.
Currently going to the site brings up the dialog to sign in with User name and password.
The expected behavior would be that the site picks up the logged in users credentials and passes them to IIS.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

What do you mean by single sign on?  For example, you can use a Microsoft Account or Open Connect by integrating with the MSAL service, or with Facebook authentication service.

You should think about using ADFS to implement SSO.
